# Best Practice for creating a Vendor account on AD for RDP into a single server?

Tags: active-directory, rdp

I have been tasked with creating an account on our Domain for an outside vendor to RDP into a single server with Admin access and have access to nothing else.

I've spent a whole day spinning my wheels since I am fairly new to AD and the processes in which to go about things like this.

I did try adding the server to the "Log On To..." option within the Vendor account properties, but there I only get "The system administrator has limited the computers you can log on with". I even added their account locally as an Admin and it still will not let anyone login.

Comment: Unattended RDP access from an external source into your network sounds like a bad idea. Does the vendor not use any remote control support software that requires the end user to initiate control?

Comment: You might consider creating a local user account for the vendor on the server in question and adding that account to the local Administrators group. That will isolate the vendor to accessing only this server.

Comment: @DanBig Agreed -- Not to my knowledge. Essentially I have a test server for our CRM system I am having them work on, which requires they have Admin rights to that server within our Domain.

Comment: @joeqwerty I would however they need Admin rights on that specific machine within our Domain. My AD knowledge is minor so making a GPO for this is not within my range of knowledge of AD and trying the "Log On To..." option seems to cause an error as if it didn't understand my servers DNS name.

Comment: Creating a local user account for the vendor on this server and adding that user account to the local Administrators group on this server will allow them to log onto and have administrator access to this server only. This will isolate the vendor so that they can only log onto this server. Since this would be a local user account the vendor would not need a user account in AD and you would not have to configure or restrict anything in AD. This "isolates" the vendor to only accessing this server and grants them no access to the AD domain.